# No need to first require 'rubygems'?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, require

I am currently reading through this guide: http://guides.rubygems.org/what-is-a-gem/

Under the third section ("Requiring code"), it says that if I run `require 'rake'`, it should fail, because "because RubyGems isn’t loaded yet.". However, when I run `require 'rake'`, (without running `require 'rubygems'`, it works! Is the guide incorrect or am I using a wrong version of Ruby or has something changed?

Answer (score 6):

You are probably running Ruby 1.9.

Per [The RubyGems User Guide](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/3#page70):

> The default Ruby 1.9 package now
>   includes RubyGems by default on most
>   platforms (presently Debian based
>   systems split this out into a separate
>   package). This means that on Ruby 1.9
>   and above, you will not need to
>   require 'rubygems' in order to load
>   gem libraries.

Answer (score 3):

If you have `RUBYOPT=rubygems` set in your environment when you launch Ruby, then Ruby Gems will automatically be required. Or if you launch ruby with the argument `-rubygems`, which is equivalent. Or if you're using Ruby 1.9 or later, Rubygems should automatically be required.

One (or more) of these things is probably true on your system.